# Animate background colour by looping through an array [jQuery]

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, for-loop

I'm trying to create something simple.

When you hover over `ul`, the background changes colour to the first item in the array. *Next time* you hover over `ul`, the background changes to the second colour in the array.

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/R3w5t/)

```
var col = ['red', 'blue', 'green'];

    $('ul').hover(function(){
        $('.container').animate({backgroundColor: 'red'});
    }, function(){
       $('.container').animate({backgroundColor: 'none'});
    });
```

The following loop takes each colour and writes it to the console. However, I'm not sure how to marry the `for loop with the hover` — **so each over moves up the array**.

```
for (i=0; i<col.length;i++){
    console.log(col[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use an index like

```
var col = ['red', 'blue', 'green'],
    index = 0;

$('ul').hover(function () {
    $('.container').stop(true).animate({
        backgroundColor: col[index++ % col.length]
    });
}, function () {
    $('.container').stop(true).animate({
        backgroundColor: 'none'
    });
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/3eGM5/)